# Is there any program that can interpolate a monospaced font from a non-monospaced font?

Tags: fonts, font-design, monospace

I am trying to create a mono-spaced version of a font. I am wondering if there's any sort of program that can interpolate one from the original. I know additional work has to be done, but I am wondering if the interpolation would reduce some of the boilerplate work.

Comment: Why would you need to interpolate? Just set the width of all fonts to the width of the widest glyph.

Comment: I imagine if only the space is changed, then there may be too much space in between individual letters within a word, and it may look confusing, as if there were two words.

Comment: Yes but what would you interpolate. For interpolation to work the fonts need to have same points.